# Adding a small title of the file/component name should be easier/mandatory

Tags: feature-request

The best questions are those with a clear structure, which makes understanding the process way more easy. Often people have a real project with different files.

So why not let each piece of code-formatted text have a small title with the corresponding file or component name? I know that some people do exactly that, but especially new users tend to forget it, so a small popup to enter a name for a code-formatted block would be really great.

Comment: Because (as far as I know) most languages aren't file name dependant as will compile regardless of what file name is, so what is the point of saying to the user what you've named the file

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be the file name, a component name or something similar would be helpful, too.

Comment: Most of the time, if you need to post the contents multiple files, the question is too broad or you're posting too much code. That should be discouraged instead of encouraged.

Comment: There's also things like SQL where you don't even have the concept of something needing to be in a file.

Answer (score 7):

What's to stop anyone from just adding a small header above a code block?
Like this:

**main.js:**

```
console.log("Hello world!");
foo("bar");

function foo(bar) {
    // TODO
}
```

Filenames rarely matter on Stack Overflow. It'd be a bit of a waste of time to implement a popup, when the available markdown already allows for a title to be added.

Comment: I stated in my question "I know that some people do exactly that, but especially new users tend to forget it, so a small popup to enter a name for a code-formatted block would be really great."

Comment: @BennettDams I think that would be more bother than it's worth. I just clicked through the first 10 questions on the front page, and this would have been useful on only one of them. Many code snippets already begin with a class name or function name, so it's unambiguous where the code is from. A pop-up would just be annoying people the majority of the time.

Comment: If a user forgets to enter a file name, was the file name really important in the first place? File names are mostly irrelevant on Stack Overflow.